# How to resize an entry box in fyne

Tags: go, fyne

Needing your help to resize a widget of fine on my app I have the following:

```golang
middleLines := container.NewHBox(app.ListLines, linesDetails)
middleLines.Resize(fyne.NewSize(1000, 10000))

containerLines := container.New(layout.NewBorderLayout(toolbarLines, nil, middleLines, nil), toolbarLines, middleLines)middleCase := container.NewHBox(app.ListCases, casesDetails)
    containerCases := container.New(layout.NewBorderLayout(toolbarCases, nil, middleCase, nil), toolbarCases, middleCase)
    tabs := container.NewAppTabs(
        container.NewTabItem("Lines", containerLines),
        container.NewTabItem("Cases", containerCases),
    )
```

that's my main window but when I run I have the following:
[Main App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okYWl.png)
As you see my text entry and my list is to small to show the text.

How can I resize this textboxes and list?

Answer (score 2):

Widget size is controlled by the container layout, so manually calling `Resize` won't have effect. See https://developer.fyne.io/faq/layout

You are placing the `middleLines` in the left element of a border layout (the parameters of the layout are top, bottom, left, right) - the edges are always shrunk so that the center can expand. If you remove it from the `left` parameter then it will expand in the center to fill the space.

Comment: "*layout are top, bottom, left, right*" ...and everything after that will be placed in the center. Also I think it is important to note that if you for example wrap an entry-widget in an h-box layout, this hinders it from extending to the full free space in the center of the border layout.